# How to display List<ComplexEditableModel> in java desktop application?

Tags: java, user-interface

I have list of objects which I want to display in GUI.
Each object is:

1) complex (it has a number of fields), thus I need several widgets to be used in GUI component which corresponds to 1 model object,

2) editable. Its properties can be changed by user via GUI (buttons, input fields and checkboxes which lay within component which corresponds to 1 model object).

How conceptually can I do this? Which UI framework and which widget to use?

Coming from android development, I have no experience in java desktop applications (by the way, in android this task can be easily accomplished by means of standart instruments (listview + its adapter)).
I have tried swing framework with its JList and JTable. But it turned out that elements within JList's cells are not editable (say, I cannot press buttons if there are a few inside Jlist's cell). The same applies to JTable.

I have googled for swing, swt, javafx etc, but didn't find direct answer how this task can be accomplished.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. It is not an option to use JTable with several columns. In fact, I want to have list of JForms or JPanels (in swing terms).